Problema con Excepciones de PHP. No consigo enviar un mensaje personalizado al crear una excepción
Estoy intentando enviar un mensaje de error personalizado al cliente mediante PHP, pero sin importar lo que intente (envolver en try catch la función, probar con echo, etc) no consigo evitar el error por defecto de PHP. En el código de abajo estoy provocando un error en la inserción del registro para que me envíe este código de error: Error en la inserción de datos del usuario, pero sin importar lo que haga recibo: Unknown column 'usuaaaaaaaario' in 'field list'
require_once '../config/credenciales.php';
require_once '../config/csrf.php';

/*=============================================
=           MARK:Valores Recibidos            =
=============================================*/

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);


$usuario = $data['usuario'];
$password = $data['contrasena'];
$token = $data['csrf_token'];

$passwordHasheado = '';

/*=============================================
=             MARK:Ingresar Usuario           =
=============================================*/

function ingresar_usuario()
{
    global $conexion, $usuario, $passwordHasheado;
    ;

    $sql_nuevo_usuario = "INSERT INTO usuarios (usuaaaaaaaario, contrasena) VALUES (?, ?)";
    $stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql_nuevo_usuario);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $usuario, $passwordHasheado);
    $insercion = $stmt->execute();

    if ($insercion === false) {
        throw new Exception('Error en la inserción de datos del usuario');
    }

    http_response_code(200);
}


/*=============================================
=              MARK:Hasehar Datos             =
=============================================*/

function hashear_contrasena()
{
    global $password, $passwordHasheado;

    $passwordHasheado = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    ingresar_usuario();
}

/*=============================================
=       MARK:Evaluar Usuario Contrasena       =
=============================================*/

$usuarioCorrecto = false;
$contrasenaCorrecta = false;
function evaluar_usuario_contrasena()
{
    global $conexion, $usuario, $password, $usuarioCorrecto, $contrasenaCorrecta;

    $comprobar_letras_numeros = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/';

    if (preg_match($comprobar_letras_numeros, $usuario) && strlen($usuario) <= 15) {
        $usuarioCorrecto = true;
    }
    if (preg_match($comprobar_letras_numeros, $password) && strlen($password) <= 20) {
        $contrasenaCorrecta = true;
    }

    if ($usuarioCorrecto && $contrasenaCorrecta) {
        hashear_contrasena();
    } else {
        throw new Exception('El usuario o contraseña fueron manipulados');
    }
}

/*=============================================
=             MARK:Evaluar Peticion           =
=============================================*/

function evaluar_peticion()
{
    global $conexion, $csrf_token, $token;

    if ($csrf_token === $token) {
        evaluar_usuario_contrasena();
    } else {
        throw new Exception('El token no coincide');
    }
}

/*============  End of Evaluar Peticion  =============*/

try {
    evaluar_peticion();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    http_response_code(400);
    echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
}

Si alguien sabe cómo puedo solucionar esto o me puede dar una pista le agradezco su ayuda

Puede que esta respuesta te sea de ayuda

@Marcos gracias pero en ese caso es para manejo de errores en mysql, lo que ando intentando realizar es un manejo de errores general, no específicamente para funciones de mysql

Pero en el post que te puso Marcos hay una respuesta mía que hace exactamente lo que pides. No solo es para MySQL sino que es para todo, los errores yo los presento tal cual y como lo dice en ese post. ¿Qué es lo que realmente quieres?

@OCHOA intenté poner el código de la funcion en un try catch como en tu respuesta pero sigo obteniendo un error de PHP en vez de mi string de error
{
    try {

       // el codigo

        if ($insercion === false) {
            throw new Exception('Error en la inserción de datos del usuario');
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        http_response_code(400);
        echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
    }
}```

Con la funcion evaluar_peticion() y evaluar_usuario_contrasena() sí se muestra el mensaje de error que puse, pero con la de ingresar_usuario() no sucede esto, quizás tenga algo que ver con el scope de las Excepciones que desconozco?

Pude dar con la solución, lo que hice fue poner toda la secuencia de instrucciones sql dentro de un try, si falla se ejecuta el catch y lanza una excepción que sí muestra mi mensaje de error personalizado, el código de la función me quedó de esta manera:
function ingresar_usuario()
{
    global $conexion, $usuario, $passwordHasheado;

    $sql_nuevo_usuario = "INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, contrasena) VALUES (?, ?)";

    try {
        $stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql_nuevo_usuario);
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $usuario, $passwordHasheado);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    } catch (Exception) {
        throw new Exception('Error en la inserción de datos del usuario');
    }
}

Si existe alguna forma mejor de hacerlo me gustaría saberlo

Pero es que justo eso dice mi respuesta, si lo tenias de otra forma ya era algo tuyo. Si te fijas en los resultados de mi respuesta son los correctos. Una lastima que el usuario nunca aceptó ni califico positivamente ninguna respuesta que le dimos

@OCHOA viendo bien tu respuesta es cierto que das con la solución, pero en mi caso por algún motivo cuando la vi no me quedó claro, sucede que cuando no se domina un tema lo que parece obvio no lo es tanto y más entre tanto código, yo le di un voto positivo a tu respuesta

Esto se llama reinventar la rueda. Ya @Marcos te sugirió una respuesta donde, activando el modo de Excepción de mysqli capturas cualquier error relativo a las consultas, sin tener que lanzar nada con throw. En caso de querer mensajes personalizados, que es lo que supongo quieres aquí, basta con identificar los códigos de error y cambiar los mensajes. En cuanto a por qué no te funcionaba inicialmente, revisa el Manual de PHP sobre las Excepciones y los ejemplos de código. Las Excepciones se capturan en un bloque try ... catch

Es decir, si en una función lanzas (throw)  una excepción,  en el bloque donde uses dicha función debes usar un try ... catch para capturar esa excepción. Revisa la función inverso() de los ejemplos del Manual (enlace en mi comentario anterior). Verás que dentro de la función se lanza la excepción y luego, donde llamas a la función se usa un try ... catch para poder capturar la excepción que es lanzada dentro de la función.
